# Typescript missing properties

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
const result: Array<{ id: string }> = list.map((x) => {
    return {
        id: x,
    };
});
```

and I am getting the following error,

> Type 'Query<{ studentsdcid: any; }, any, {}>' is missing the following properties from type '{ studentsdcid: string; }[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 22 more.ts(2740)

Not really sure what I need to change here.

Comment: Create a minimal, reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not include all the relevant code, so I can't tell you what exactly you are doing wrong, but I *can* explain the error and guess what you are doing wrong.

`length`, `pop`, `push`, `concat`, and "22 more" are all properties of the interface `Array<Type>`, which is the generic type you declared for `result`.

You are getting that error because you are using 'Query<{ studentsdcid: any; }, any, {}>' in a place where an `Array` is expected, and `Query` is not an `Array` nor extends it.

Comment: This is really late and apologies, but this happened because I wasn't awaiting an query.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript probably isn't able to figure out the type of `list`.

Have you declared : `const list: string[] = []` somewhere in your code above?

If yes, and you still get the error, add in typing for x like this:

```
const result: Array<{ id: string }> = list.map((x: string) => {
                return {
                    id: x,
                };
            });
```

But given the logs of your question, it seems the issue is somewhere later in code where it is using the `result` object.